# TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and I got the below code from one of the internet forums and it's not working if I invoke the function from the Javascript class like below. When I try to execute I get the below errors and  I am unable to figure out whats the reason. Can someone please help me with what I am missing here?

[image: Error Message]

```js
var person1 = {
  FirstName: "First Name1",
  LastName: "Last name1",
  Age: 30,
  EMailAddresses: [
    "FirstName.LastName@msn.com"
  ],
  Children: [{
    FirstName: "Child First Name1",
    LastName: "Child Last Name1",
    Age: 2
  }, {
    FirstName: "Child First Name2",
    LastName: "Child Last Name2",
    Age: 5
  }]
};

var person2 = {
  LastName: "LastName2",
  Age: 33,
  EMailAddresses: [
    "LastName2@gmail.com",
    "LastName2@hotmail.com"
  ],
  Children: [{
    FirstName: "Child First Name1",
    LastName: "Child Last Name1",
    Age: 3
  }, {
    FirstName: "Micky",
    LastName: "Mouse",
    Age: 5
  }]
};



class MasterClass {
  async getDifferencs(objectA, objectB) {

    var propertyChanges = [];
    var objectGraphPath = ["this"];

    (function(a, b) {
      if (a.constructor == Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          objectGraphPath.push("[" + i.toString() + "]");
          arguments.callee(a[i], b[i]);

          objectGraphPath.pop();
        }
      } else if (a.constructor == Object || (a.constructor != Number &&
          a.constructor != String && a.constructor != Date &&
          a.constructor != RegExp && a.constructor != Function &&
          a.constructor != Boolean)) {
        for (var property in a) {
          objectGraphPath.push(("." + property));
          if (a[property].constructor != Function) {
            arguments.callee(a[property], b[property]);
          }
          objectGraphPath.pop();
        }
      } else if (a.constructor != Function) { // filter out functions
        if (a != b) {
          propertyChanges.push({
            "Property": objectGraphPath.join(""),
            "ObjectA": a,
            "ObjectB": b
          });
        }
      }
    })(objectA, objectB);
    return propertyChanges;
  }
}

var my_class = new MasterClass();
var differences = my_class.getDifferencs(person1, person2);

console.log(differences);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function test() {
  console.log( arguments.callee === test ); // true
})();
```

`arguments.callee`, which refers to the function itself, is not available in strict mode. You may give a name to the function, and use that name as reference:

```
async getDifferencs(objectA, objectB) {

  var propertyChanges = [];
  var objectGraphPath = ["this"];

  (function _self(a, b) { // <--- (1)
    if (a.constructor == Array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        objectGraphPath.push("[" + i.toString() + "]");
        _self(a[i], b[i]); // <--- (2)

        objectGraphPath.pop();
      }
    } else if (a.constructor == Object || (a.constructor != Number &&
        a.constructor != String && a.constructor != Date &&
        a.constructor != RegExp && a.constructor != Function &&
        a.constructor != Boolean)) {
      for (var property in a) {
        objectGraphPath.push(("." + property));
        if (a[property].constructor != Function) {
          _self(a[property], b[property]); // <--- (3)
        }
        objectGraphPath.pop();
      }
    } else if (a.constructor != Function) {
      if (a != b) {
        propertyChanges.push({
          "Property": objectGraphPath.join(""),
          "ObjectA": a,
          "ObjectB": b
        });
      }
    }
  })(objectA, objectB);
  
  return propertyChanges;
}
```

Comment: Thank You!.  it worked. I also tried to assign "this" to "self" and called the function using self but somehow it did not work. Your approach worked thanks a lot to save my time.